# `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` flags `!LaTeX Error: Command \quoting already defined.`

Tags: babel, quoting

`[spanish]{babel}` flags `!LaTeX Error: Command \quoting already defined.`

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. Mon 26/11/2018
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:
%  \usepackage[spanish]{babel} flags !LaTeX Error: Command \quoting already defined.
%=======================
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=1cm]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}
\textbf{Blindtext}, one of the \LaTeX\ packages 

\medskip

\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=2cm,rightmargin=3cm,font=   {it,raggedleft},vskip=3mm]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}
\textbf{Blindtext}, one of the \LaTeX\ packages 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Obviously you will have to choose which quoting environment (the one from spanish or the one from the quoting package) you want to retain.

Comment: No comprendo. It compiles without error with `\usepackage[english,italian,frenchb,ngerman]{babel}`

Comment: Sure, none of this languages define a quoting environment, but spanish.ldf does.

Comment: Some `babel` modules do more than just providing translations of `\chaptername` and the date format. Some also change the typesetting of other aspects of the document in non-trivial ways: Amongst the many things that `spanish` does (or can do) is that it defines a `quoting` environment. That clashes with `quoting`. If in doubt it is not enough to consult the `babel` documentation, one will also have to have a look at the `babel-<language>` docs (e.g. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an unfortunate state of things:

1. `babel-spanish` defines a `quoting` environment
2. the `quoting` package defines a `quoting` environment

Both environments cannot coexist.

Note that `babel-spanish` internally uses its own `quoting` for its quoting mechanism, unless you use the `es-noquoting` option.

A way out is

```
\usepackage[...,spanish,es-noquoting,...]{babel}
\let\quoting\relax\let\endquoting\relax

\usepackage{quoting}
```

If needed, the quoting feature of `babel-spanish` can be realized with `csquotes`, which is much more powerful.